# Splitting line manually at intersection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, overlapping-features, splitting, digitizing

I would like to split the CA line at the exact point where it intersects the NC line. I try to use the Split Features Tool (scissors) in QGIS but it doesn't cut the line at the exact point of the intersection.

[image]

Is there any tool to cut a line manually at the exact point of an intersection? (I know there's also the Split Line algorithm but I don't want to create a new layer each time I need to split a line).

Comment: Is snapping to vertices active?

Comment: yes but there are no vertices in the intersection, maybe I could create a vertice in the NC line where I and then cut the other line at this vertice

Comment: And snapping at intersections?

Comment: do you know a way to snap at intersections? If there is a vertice in the intersections it works, but if there is not I don't know how to do it

Comment: If you click on  the Edit Features in Place button on the top of the Processing Toobox, the  Split with lines tool is available to work on your edit layer's selected line.  No new layer is created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the snapping toolbar activate the "snap to intersections" option (3rd button from the right), and make sure you have set snapping to "all layers" (2nd button from the left).

[image]